# Is "shutting down X off of Y" grammatical?

Tags: grammar

I know for a fact that "shutting down X" is grammatical, but I am not sure if you can add the verb complement "off of Y" after it. We already have the adverb "down", so I don't think we can add a verb complement starting with another adverb "off". We can say "remove X off of Y", but I don't think the former phrase is grammatical.

For example:

> They were right about shutting down the Infowars channel off of
>   YouTube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shutting down the Infowars channel off of YouTube.

can be:
**shutting down** the Infowars channel **on** YouTube.

OR
**taking down** the Infowars channel **from** YouTube

OR
**taking** the Inforwars channel **down** from YouTube

OR
**taking** the Infowars channel **off** [of] YouTube
OR
**taking** the Infowars channel **down off** of YouTube

[off-topic: that would be great coz it ain't news]

You can take something|| off a/the wall.
You can take something down|| off a/the wall.

However, shut down (close, often a business) is a phrasal verb that does not involve an imaginary surface.

take down can be a phrasal verb but here implies that YouTube is like a surface.

(I may have forgotten some variation or other.)

off of implies a surface or waves: They took him off the air.

Comment: I know my personal bias against "off of" may be unreasonable, but is it worth adding that any use of "off of" can be replaced with just "off"? Fewer words good?

Comment: "taking the Infowars channel down off of YouTube" doesn't sound grammatical.

Comment: Why is "taking the Infowars channel down off of YouTube" grammatical while "shutting down the Infowars channel off of YouTube" is ungrammatical?

Comment: I explained that: take off is like a surface, shut down does not involve an imaginary surface. Take down does. Sorry, but "taking the x channel down off [of] YouTube" is redundant but OK. "Take those shoes down off [of] the table now!"

Comment: Since it's redundant shouldn't there be a comma between down and off?

Comment: @frbsfok Nope, they become "three-word verbs" pragmatically.